# Anchor tag does not work in RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, report, rdlc

I am using RDLC report with VS2010 and postgreSQL

I have one case in which i need to use anchor tag

i have one query that gives me so many column but i will show you only one that contains  tag

Column Name : **Documents**

**Result :**

```
"<a href='sad_pdf_1.pdf' target='_blank'>sad_pdf_1.pdf</a>"
```

in report i have one textbox in which i have write in "Expression" property like

```
=Fields!Documents.Value
```

i have also set Place holder property to support HTML Tag

But i am not able to click on that hyper link when it being binds on page.

**Screen shot**

[image: fffffffff]

Comment: Please create Placeholder, it is supporting HTML tabs

Comment: I have already added place holder but it does not work

Comment: I have tried in test project and found that Hyperlinks are not working in Report Viewer but working in Exported Excel, PDF and Word

Comment: thank for helping.now my anchor tag started working but i have faced new issue that target property of <a> set as "_top". how to change it to "_blank"

Answer (score 0):

Please try below configuration:
[image]